# Remove link from parent menu if it has sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove link from parent menu anchor if it has submenus

```
<ul class="sitemap-ul">
    <li> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/aboutus/">about Us</a> <!-- Remove link-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/mission">mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="/vision">vission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/media">Media</a> <!-- Remove link-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/media/news">news</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should show us what you tried, as you say you want to use jquery

Comment: I tried https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEgqjm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove the `<a>` elements themselves but leave behind their text content you can use `:has()` to get the relevant `li` with submenus, then `replaceWith()` on the child `a` elements, like this:

```js
$('.sitemap-ul > li:has(ul) > a').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).text();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sitemap-ul">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/mission">mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="/vision">vission</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a href="/media">Media</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/media/news">news</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```js
$('.sitemap-ul > li:has(ul) > a').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sitemap-ul">
    <li> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/aboutus/">about Us</a> <!-- Remove link-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/mission">mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="/vision">vission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/media">Media</a> <!-- Remove link-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/media/news">news</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE :** In case you just want to replace `a` tag with text then use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents) method with [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap) method.

```js
$('.sitemap-ul > li:has(ul) > a')
  // get children element
  .contents()
  // unwrap them
  .unwrap()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sitemap-ul">
  <li> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a href="/aboutus/">about Us</a>
    <!-- Remove link-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/mission">mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="/vision">vission</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="/media">Media</a>
    <!-- Remove link-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/media/news">news</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It removes the text also

Comment: Very Good Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sitemap-ul > li').each(function(){
    if($('ul', this).length > 0){
        $(this).closest("a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution by using vanilla js for you.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".sitemap-ul li")

Array.from(elements).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.children.length > 1) {
    el.removeChild(el.children[0])
  }
});
```